# Subtracting Dates with multiple Joins Involved

Tags: sql-server

I was hoping someone could help me.

I have the following 5 tables:

### tblCustomer

```
CustomerID   CustomerName   
 -------     ------------
   1         ABC Bank     
   2         Chase Bank
```

### tblOrderType

```
OrderTypeID    OrderTypeName   
 ----------    ------------
   1           Assignment     
   2           LienRelease
```

### tblActivity

```
ActivityID        ActivityName   
 ----------       ------------
   1              Received     
   2              Keyed
   3              Printed
   4              Delivered To Customer
```

### tblOrder

```
OrderID        CustomerID      OrderTypeID   LoanNumber
 ----------    ------------    -----------   ----------
   1           1                1            45584565
   2           1                1            45566856
   3           1                1            45565584
   4           1                1            45588545
```

### tblOrderActivity

```
OrderID        ActivityID    ActivityDate
 ----------    -----------   ----------
   1           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   1           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM  
   1           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM 
   1           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM  
   2           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   2           3             2014-12-16 10:33:09 AM
   3           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   3           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   3           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
   3           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM
   4           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   4           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   4           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
```

The information has been changed for protection purposes. So say I need to be able to list all orders by customer and the time difference (in minutes) from:
    -“Received” to “Keyed”     as [TurnTime1]
    -“Keyed” to “Printed”      as [TurnTime2]
    -“Printed” to “Delivered”  as [TurnTime3]
    -“Received” to “Delivered” as [TurnTime4]
I also need to return CustomerName, OrderTypeName, LoanNumber, TurnTime1, TurnTime2, TurnTime3,and TurnTime4. I believe I am close, however, I have tried two different ways of doing this, both ways aren't correct and I am stuck. The first option, includes only 4 rows with the value of "0" each TurnTime Column. The second option, includes over 600 rows. I believe this should be returning only 11 rows with data and maybe a few additional rows where the data doesn't meet the stipulations. Here is what I have so far:

### Option 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblOrder.LoanNumber,
(DATEPART(mi,(tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate - tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime1],
(DATEPART(mi,(tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate - tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime2],
(DATEPART(mi,(tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate - tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime3],
(DATEPART(mi,(tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate - tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime4]
FROM tblOrder
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity
ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblOrderActivity.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblActivity
ON tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType
ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
INNER JOIN tblCustomer
ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblActivity WHERE ActivityName IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblorder.LoanNumber, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate;
```

### Option 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblOrder.LoanNumber,
(DATEPART(mi,(TT2.ActivityDate - TT1.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime1],
(DATEPART(mi,(TT3.ActivityDate - TT2.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime2],
(DATEPART(mi,(TT4.ActivityDate - TT3.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime3],
(DATEPART(mi,(TT4.ActivityDate - TT1.ActivityDate))) AS [TurnTime4]
FROM tblOrder
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity AS TT1
ON tblOrder.OrderID = TT1.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity AS TT2
ON tblOrder.OrderID = TT2.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity AS TT3
ON tblOrder.OrderID = TT3.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity AS TT4
ON tblOrder.OrderID = TT4.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblActivity AS TA1
ON TT1.ActivityID = TA1.ActivityID
INNER JOIN tblActivity AS TA2
ON TT2.ActivityID = TA2.ActivityID
INNER JOIN tblActivity AS TA3
ON TT3.ActivityID = TA3.ActivityID
INNER JOIN tblActivity AS TA4
ON TT4.ActivityID = TA4.ActivityID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType
ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
INNER JOIN tblCustomer
ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblActivity WHERE ActivityName IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblorder.LoanNumber, TT1.ActivityDate,
TT2.ActivityDate, TT3.ActivityDate, TT4.ActivityDate;
```

Comment: First thing `SELECT DISTINCT..GROUP BY` is, at best, a redundancy.Second thing your subquery probably needs to be correlated.Third one I dont get the self JOINs.

Comment: In your house, do you attach post-it notes to your shoes with the words 'shoes' written on them?

Comment: Neither of those comments are helping me get to my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02c1c/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tblCustomer
(
    CustomerID int,
    CustomerName varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO tblCustomer
VALUES
(  1, 'ABC Bank'),
(  2, 'Chase Bank')

create table tblOrderType
(
    OrderTypeID int,
    OrderTypeName varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO tblOrderType
VALUES
(  1, 'Assignment'),
(  2, 'LienRelease')


create table tblActivity
(
    ActivityID int,
    ActivityName varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO tblActivity
VALUES
(  1, 'Received'),
(  2, 'Keyed'),
(  3, 'Printed'),
(  4, 'Delivered To Customer')

CREATE TABLE tblOrder
(
    OrderID int,
    CustomerID int,
    OrderTypeID int,
    LoanNumber int
)

INSERT INTO tblOrder
VALUES
(  1, 1, 1, 45584565),
(  2, 1, 1, 45566856),
(  3, 1, 1, 45565584),
(  4, 1, 1, 45588545)

CREATE TABLE tblOrderActivity
(
    OrderID int,
    ActivityID int,
    ActivityDate DateTime
)

INSERT INTO tblOrderActivity
VALUES
(1, 1, '2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM'),
(1, 2, '2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM'),  
(1, 3, '2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM'), 
(1, 4, '2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM'),  
(2, 1, '2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM'),
(2, 3, '2014-12-16 10:33:09 AM'),
(3, 1, '2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM'),
(3, 2, '2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM'),
(3, 3, '2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM'),
(3, 4, '2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM'),
(4, 1, '2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM'),
(4, 2, '2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM'),
(4, 3, '2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName,O.OrderId, OT.OrderTypeName, O.LoanNumber,
(DATEDIFF(mi, Received.ActivityDate, Keyed.ActivityDate)) AS [TurnTime1],
(DATEDIFF(mi, Keyed.ActivityDate, Printed.ActivityDate)) AS [TurnTime2],
(DATEDIFF(mi, Printed.ActivityDate, Delivered.ActivityDate)) AS [TurnTime3],
(DATEDIFF(mi, Received.ActivityDate, Delivered.ActivityDate)) AS [TurnTime4]
FROM tblCustomer C
INNER JOIN tblOrder O
    ON O.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
INNER JOIN tblOrderType OT
    ON OT.OrderTypeID = O.OrderTypeID
INNER JOIN tblOrderActivity Received
    ON Received.OrderID = O.OrderID AND Received.ActivityId = 1
LEFT JOIN tblOrderActivity Keyed
    ON Keyed.OrderID = O.OrderID AND Keyed.ActivityId = 2
LEFT JOIN tblOrderActivity Printed
    ON Printed.OrderID = O.OrderID AND Printed.ActivityId = 3
LEFT JOIN tblOrderActivity Delivered
    ON Delivered.OrderID = O.OrderID AND Delivered.ActivityId = 4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02c1c/4/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMERNAME | ORDERID | ORDERTYPENAME | LOANNUMBER | TURNTIME1 | TURNTIME2 | TURNTIME3 | TURNTIME4 |
|--------------|---------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     ABC Bank |       1 |    Assignment |   45584565 |        48 |        29 |       383 |       460 |
|     ABC Bank |       2 |    Assignment |   45566856 |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
|     ABC Bank |       3 |    Assignment |   45565584 |        48 |        29 |       383 |       460 |
|     ABC Bank |       4 |    Assignment |   45588545 |        48 |        29 |    (null) |    (null) |
```

If you need to eliminate the rows with `NULL`s in, just change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: this is very close, however, shouldn't TurnTime 4 be larger than all of the others since it is essentially the total time of all Activities?

Comment: would it work to return in hours for TurnTime4 and multiply by 60? or is there a better way to do that?
    ((DATEPART(hh, (Delivered.ActivityDate - Received.ActivityDate)))* 60) AS [TurnTime4]

Comment: @zreaper you are right, the issue is I used DATEPART when I should have used DATEDIFF, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @zreaper it should be noted that in your question, where you use DATEPART, this gets the number of minutes in the current hour. So 8:02 returns 2 and 9:02 also returns 2. DATEDIFF gets the difference between the two dates in whatever unit you want. So DATEDIFF(mi, '09:02', '08:02') returns 60 minutes. Hope this helps.

Comment: when I change it to use the SELECT Statement you included above, it returns negative numbers for TurnTime3 and TurnTime4. TurnTime3 should be 1080 and TurnTime4 should be 1140

Comment: @zreaper if you use DATEDIFF(mi, firsttime, secondtime) where firsttime is before the secondtime it should return a positive number however if you use DATEDIFF(mi, secondtime, firsttime) it would return a negative number. I had this round the wrong way in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94b50/1)**

you can use `case based aggregation` with a substraction to get the difference in time between activities for each order of the customer.

```
select C.CustomerNAme, OT.OrderTypeName, O.LoanNumber, 
      max ( case when OA.ActivityID =2 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end)  - 
      max ( case When OA.ActivityID =1 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end) as TurnTime1,
      max ( case when OA.ActivityID =3 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end)  - 
      max ( case When OA.ActivityID =2 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end) as TurnTime2,
      max ( case when OA.ActivityID =4 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end)  - 
      max ( case When OA.ActivityID =3 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end) as TurnTime3,
      max ( case when OA.ActivityID =4 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end)  - 
      max ( case When OA.ActivityID =1 then datediff(minute,0,OA.ActivityDate) end) as TurnTime4


FROM tblCustomer C
JOIN tblOrder O
on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
JOIN tblOrderActivity OA
on OA.OrderID = O.OrderID
JOIN tblOrderType OT
on OT.OrderTypeID = O.OrderTypeID
GROUP BY C.CustomerName, OT.OrderTypeName, O.LoanNumber
```

Comment: @zreaper, i don't see negative values. here is fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94b50/1

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a simple matter of creating a join table for each group that you want based on the table activity. Note though that I am assuming that an activity can only be performed once.

```
Select tblCustomer.CustomerName, 
       tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, 
       tblOrder.LoanNumber,
       DATEDiff(mi,tblOrderReceived.ActivityDate, tblOrderKeyed.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime1],
       DATEDiff(mi,tblOrderKeyed.ActivityDate, tblOrderPrinted.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime2],
       DATEDiff(mi,tblOrderPrinted.ActivityDate, tblOrderDelivered.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime3],
       DATEDiff(mi,tblOrderReceived.ActivityDate, tblOrderDelivered.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime4]
From tblOrder
    INNER JOIN tblOrderType
        ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
    INNER JOIN tblCustomer
        ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
    Left Outer Join tblOrderActivity tblOrderReceived
        ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    Left Outer Join tblOrderActivity tblOrderKeyed
        ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    Left Outer Join tblOrderActivity tblOrderPrinted
        ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    Left Outer Join tblOrderActivity tblOrderDelivered
        ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    Left Outer Join tblActivity
        ON tblOrderReceived.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID
            OR tblOrderKeyed.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID
            OR tblOrderPrinted.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID
            OR tblOrderDelivered.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID
Where tblOrderReceived.ActivityID = 1
    And tblOrderKeyed.ActivityID = 2
    And tblOrderPrinted.ActivityID = 3
    And tblOrderDelivered.ActivityID = 4
    And tblOrder.OrderID In (Select ActivityMask.OrderID from tblOrderActivity ActivityMask)
```

Comment: added a mask for the select in the where clause as I feel that might be the reason for that issue. Which line does that error occur on?

Comment: thanks anyway for your help,the above recommendation seems to work best.